# Can't install libpugixml-dev on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install libpugixml-dev on Ubuntu 12.04, but whenever I try to do it, the following error appears:

http://prntscr.com/jf4kii

Translation: Impossible to find package libpugixml-dev

I don't know how to compile pugixml on Ubuntu either, so this is kind of frustrating me...

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update` after  try this `sudo apt-get install libpugixml-dev`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I had already tried that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No libpugixml* for Ubuntu 12.04

Easy to build: Get the Ubuntu 14 source, pugixml_1.2.orig.tar.gz http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pugixml/pugixml_1.2.orig.tar.gz ... and the patch, if you want the static `libpugixml.a` → http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pugixml/pugixml_1.2-2.debian.tar.gz

Build libpugixml all, example :

```
tar xvf pugixml_1.2.orig.tar.gz
cd pugixml_1.2/
cmake scripts/ && make && sudo make install
       // Provides /usr/local/{{lib/libpugixml.so*}, {include/*.hpp}}
```

The result, in a package :  libpugixml-all_1.2-1ubuntu12_amd64.deb → https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kSvEYax8jKuyDL6Feinsx_q8VcrqEwA7/view?usp=sharing   ( `libpugixml.a` is included.)